# Webpack image-loader only minifying png's

Tags: javascript, webpack

Im still new to webpack so having some teething problems. The only images that are being minimized / loaded are pngs. I have tried using image-loader and url-loader, they both have the same result. Also tried reordering the test types.

here is the config in my webpack.config.js file using file-loader

```
images: {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpg|svg)$/i,
        exclude: /scss/,
        loaders: [
            'url-loader?limit=1&name=images/[path][name].[ext]&context=./resources/assets/src/images',
            'image-webpack'
        ]
    }
```

and file loader

```
    images: {
    test: /\.(gif|png|jpg|svg)$/i,
    exclude: /scss/,
    loaders: [
        'file?name=images/[path][name].[ext]&context=./resources/assets/src/images',
        'image-webpack'
    ]
}
```

They both also have imageWebpackLoader

```
imageWebpackLoader: {
    optimizationLevel: 4,
    pregressive: true,
    interlaced: true,
    svgo: {
        plugins: [{
            removeViewBox: false
        }, {
            removeEmptyAttrs: false
        }]
    }
}
```

My src tree looks like this

```
├── content
│   └── registration-confirmation.png
├── decoration
│   ├── accordion-arrow-open.png
│   ├── accordion-arrow.png
│   ├── homepage-postcode-decoration.png
│   ├── paper-background.png
│   └── tape.png
├── homepage
│   ├── blast-from-the-past.jpg
│   ├── feature-arangement.png
│   ├── feature-delivery.png
│   ├── feature-flowers.png
│   ├── hero-mobile.jpg
│   ├── hero.jpg
│   ├── next-weeks-flowers.jpg
│   └── welcome.jpg
├── icons
│   ├── burger-menu-bar.png
│   ├── burger-menu-item-active.png
│   ├── checkbox-active.png
│   ├── checkbox-error.png
│   ├── checkbox.png
│   ├── copy-link.png
│   ├── dropdown-arrow-error.png
│   ├── dropdown-arrow.png
│   ├── email.png
│   ├── radiobutton-active.png
│   └── radiobutton.png
└── svg
    └── freddies_flowers_logo.svg
```

but build looks like this:

```
.
├── decoration
│   ├── accordion-arrow-open.png
│   ├── accordion-arrow.png
│   ├── paper-background.png
│   └── tape.png
└── icons
    ├── burger-menu-bar.png
    ├── burger-menu-item-active.png
    ├── checkbox-active.png
    ├── checkbox.png
    ├── dropdown-arrow-error.png
    ├── dropdown-arrow.png
    ├── radiobutton-active.png
    └── radiobutton.png
```

Comment: Have you tried without imageWebpackLoader to see if it works without it?

Comment: Yes, first thing I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have jpeg in your test pattern but not jpg and all your files have the jpg extension.

Also, the name parameter looks fishy. It looks like you are repeating the *images* subdir at the front part of the path, but the context parameter already specifies *images* as part of the path. Is the path *images/images*?

I would try the following:

`'file?name=[path][name].[ext]&context=./resources/assets/src/images'`

I would also try not using the context parameter at all and using `include` instead:

```
images: {
    test: /\.(gif|png|jpg|svg)$/i,
    include: './resources/assets/src/images',
    loaders: [
        'file?name=[path][name].[ext]',
        'image-webpack'
    ]
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I cloned your git repo, those files aren't being copied because they are not referenced by any JS or CSS that is being built by the webpack build. They are only referenced by static HTML, or assets outside of the webpack entry point. The webpack loaders will only copy files that have to be loaded while building the entry point. If you want to copy files that aren't part of the application being built, you could consider using the [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin).

Otherwise, the resources will be copied to build once you use them in the application.

**Example**

The build directory does not include `checkbox-error.png`, but it does include `checkbox-active.png`. There is a style rule in `_checkboxes.scss` that references `checkbox-active.png` but nothing that references `checkbox-error.png`. I added a style rule that references `checkbox-error.png` like so:

```
    &:checked.error {
        + label {

            text-decoration: none;
            $image: $img-icon-path + 'checkbox-error.png';
            @include pseudo-el(before, 32px, 30px) {
                background: url($image) no-repeat;
            }
        }
    }
```

and re-ran the build. Now `checkbox-error.png` is in the output directory.

Comment: Oh yeah, just tried removing that. But still doesn't work

Comment: I've changed it to this but still no luck

Comment: `images: {
            test: /\.(gif|png|jpg|svg)$/i,
            exclude: /scss/,
            include: PATHS.src + 'images/',
            loaders: [
                'file?name=[path][name].[ext]',
                'image-webpack'
            ]
        }`



Sorry about the formatting, this is what im running `webpack --progress --colors --watch --config webpack.development.config.js` if that makes a difference.

Comment: is it still the exact same behavior? is it always the exact same files from your list above getting copied to the output directory?

Comment: Yes it always just all the png

Comment: Your output listing above does not include all pngs. For example, *email.png* is not in the output directory. Is there something different about the files, size maybe?

Comment: Well spotted, email.png is very small, but it would be no larger than burger-menu-bar.png

Comment: I tried using url-loader again written with a limiter on it and now only one png file is computed, does this help `'url-loader?limit=8192`

Comment: url-loader will inline images smaller than the limit - storing their content directly in the javascript/css file instead of copying the actual file into the output directory. can you run your app and see if the images are visible and/or look in the javascript file and see if references in the javascript or css specify the image bytes instead of a url to the image?

Comment: Nope, no reference to them. But im using extractTextPlugin to generate a seperate css file, so css won't be inlined with the JS

Comment: When you say "no reference to them", do you mean no javascript or css is referencing the images - or - the bytes are not present at the locations where they should be inlined? You can look in the extracted css file for inlined bytes as well. If you just don't have a reference - add one for one of the images that isn't getting loaded.

Comment: Not sure what you mean in the last sentence. But there is no file where it should be or anywhere near where it should be, there is nothing in the css of js that looks or named like the file.

Here is my repo if it helps to run it - need npm install and bower install then just npm start to run it https://github.com/alex-windett/freddies-flowers

Comment: Those files aren't being referenced by any JS or CSS that is part of the webpack build. Thats why they aren't being copied. I updated the answer.

Comment: Also - just added an example for "adding a reference" to an image that results in it being copied to the output directory.

Comment: Oooh, OK that makes sense. Thank you so much !